# "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tgan'"

Tags: python, installation, pip

I tried installing a package called 'tgan' (which is relatively new) but I keep getting

> > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tgan'

I made sure that my requirements satisfy the package (python 3.5,3.6 or 3.7) and I installed tgan using pip on the CMD, as well as Conda. However, when I try to install it directly on my IDE (Spyder) I get the following error:

```
pip install tgan

Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
```

Here's my full code:

```
from tgan.model import TGANModel
import pandas as pd

all_data = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/Mahmoud164033/Desktop/Conference Paper/ML 
Models/Compiled_data.xlsx', sheet_name= 'c1,4', header = 0)

data = all_data.iloc[:,2:].values
continuous_columns = [4]

tgan = TGANModel(continuous_columns)
model = tgan.fit(data)
```

Here's the documentation:
https://sdv.dev/TGAN/

Update: It turns out that I had Python 3.8 installed on Conda (the documentation says it only works with Python 3.5,3.6 and 3.7) and after downgrading to Python 3.7.5 the package works.

Comment: have you tried restarting the IDE

Comment: Yes, multiple times and I even tried updating it.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I am not using that package until you said but I try it to install that and it installs version 0.0 but I supposed you want to latest version(0.1.0). So try this way.

> pip install tgan==0.1.0

And another thing is they require pandas>=0.23.4 and tensorflow<2.0,>=1.13.0
Plz concern that also.

Comment: I still get the "The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect" error

Comment: @Mahmoud_iLoutfy do you can install another module?, for sure, It is not your python configuration problem.